# Double to array of int

Tags: c, int, double

I want to transform a `double` into an array of two `int`s:

For example when c=0.09:

```
 double c=0.09; ===> int tab [2] ={0, 09}
```

I find `tab[0]` with `(int)c`, but not `tab[1]`!

```
void char_To_Tab_Int_W(char chartab[]){
     int taille=strlen(chartab);
     int j=0,y=0,i,h;
     while(j<taille){
         char c=chartab[j]; // code ascii
         printf("\n c= %d",(int)c);
         h=0;
         chW[0]='\0';chW[1]='\0';
         while((int)c!=46){  
             sprintf(chW,"%s",Concat_String(chW,c));
             chW[h]=c;
             j++;h++;
             c=chartab[j];
         }// fin while et remplissage de ch
         printf("\n==>ch= %s",chW);
         int val= atoi(chW);
         printf("\t==>val=%d",val);
         tmpIntW[y]=val;
         printf("\t==>tmpIntW[%d]=%d",y,tmpIntW[y]);
         j++;y++;
     }

     printf("\nCharTabRecu : ");
     for(i=0;i<y;i++){
         printf("%d  ",tmpIntW[i]);
     }
  }
```

And in `main()` :

```
int main(){
    double w=0.09;
    printf("w1=%d", (int)w);
    printf("\nreste= %f" ,(w-(int)w));
    int j;
    char chartabw[100];
    sprintf(chartabw, "%f", w);
    char_To_Tab_Int_W(chartabw); // je rempli tmpIntTabRecu
    printf("\nTabW : ");
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
          tabW[j]=tmpIntW[j];
          printf("%d ",tabW[j]);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

but this does not give me the result.

Any idea?

Comment: 1) Think. 2) Do some maths. 3) Use pen, paper and coffee. 4) Write code.

Comment: You can't store `09`. The preceding `0` indicates that it is an octal number, but then `9` isn't a valid octal number. So, `int tab [2] ={0, 09};` raises an error: `error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant`. Your only hope would be to store `9` in `tab[1]`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no "do my homework" service.

Comment: why you want to do such a thing..? 
For tab 1, you can use a loop to calculate the number. But the leading zeros will be omitted. If you want those zeros, its better to use and char*[] to store values as string. Because leading zero is will give another interpretation..

Comment: If you always want two decimals, then just scale the int by 100.

Comment: 0.09 isn't exactly representable in binary floating-point, so you can't split them anyway without proper rounding

Answer (score 0):

> to transform a double into an array of two int

Use `round()`

---

OP's code attempts to separate the `double` using a printed version (to six decimal places) using various text/math - many issues (buffer size, rounding, negatives).

Let us try a new approach and use whole numbers.

It appears that not only is code separating into 2 integers,  the factional portion is to be *rounded* to the nearest 0.01. Of key concern is that the number should be rounded, before separating, to deal with the rounding effect propagating in to the integer portion. [@Lưu Vĩnh Phúc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948197/double-to-array-of-int/32955232#comment53725858_32948197)

```
// Since converting to `int`, insure number is not too big.
assert(INT_MIN <= c && c <= INT_MAX);

// scale and round
double t = round(c*100.0);

tab[1] = (int) fmod(t, 100.0);
tab[0] = (int) (t/100.0);

printf("%d.%02d\n",  tab[0], abs(tab[1]));
```

---

Another approach is slightly simpler.

```
long long tll = (long long) round(c*100.0);
tab[1] = (int) (tll%100);
tab[0] = (int) (tll/100);
```

---

`double c=0.09; ===> int tab [2] ={0, 09}` is bad C code as integer constants beginning with `0` are consider octal and `09` is invalid octal.  [@Cool Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948197/double-to-array-of-int/32955232#comment53721104_32948197)